# How to create a pie chart like structure in CS3?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, cs3

I'm designing a web template in Photoshop and I need to create a style which looks like a pie with cut pieces. **How could I create it using Photoshop CS3 tools? Or it can only created in Illustrator?**

Any extra advice on how to create pie graphics in Illustrator or Photoshop will be greatly appreciated.

[image: here my try] need to show the circle like cut pieces like pie chat now i created this in Photoshop

Comment: I think you mean [Ellipse Tool](http://pe-images.s3.amazonaws.com/basics/type-on-a-path/photoshop-ellipse-tool.gif)?

Comment: @Vivek I'm not sure why Scott's post doesn't answer your question, could you maybe provide an example of what it is you're trying to create?

Comment: can you explain why what Scott posted doesnt answer your question if you use the `Graph Tool`?  At the moment, when you read this entire question and the comments it almost looks like you haven't attempted the answer and are wanting someone to design it for you.  That may not be your intention but I am also confused on why the answer wont work.

Comment: So are you looking to illustrate "pie" meaning a bakery item? Not a graphical representation of data?

Comment: Just create clipping masks on top of your circle layer.

Comment: Your added image has merely confused the matter, and slightly befuddled me as to why you feel my answer may be inadequate. (Note: prior to the question edit, you asked for ***either*** a Photoshop or Illustrator method. I provided an Illustrator method which is much easier than anything Photoshop offers. The edit to the question now makes it read as if you **only** want a Photoshop solution.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a graph tool in Illustrator.

[image]

This is the resulting artwork when using the **Pie Graph Tool** in Illustrator:

[image]

If you want a more elaborate appearance you can:

- Create your pie graph
- ungroup
- apply `Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel`
- expand
- alter for better appearance.

[image]

This is not even half as easy to accomplish with Photoshop. Create it in Illustrator then copy/paste to Photoshop if needed.

Comment: moreover am asking  not  a  pie chart i need a circle which has a pie like structure with pieces like pie chart :(

Comment: Isn't the above a "pie like structure with pieces"? Did you even bother to try the Pie Graph Tool to see what it creates? How about at least **a little effort** on your part? Don't get overly hung up on the **name** of the tool.

Comment: sorry i din't worked with illustrator before thats why i asked you up there is that think available on `Adobe CS3`

Comment: The Graph Tool was first seen in Illustrator 5.0 I believe. (and hasn't really been updated much since) It's been there for a couple decades and is present in Illustrator CS3 (v13).

Comment: This may help: http://www.deke.com/content/dekes-techniques-018-creating-a-3d-pie-chart